# unity3d google play error [DF-RPC-01]

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play, in-app-purchase

I am developing an Android mobile game. Now I am integrating unity-IAP with Unity3d.

I am trying to test google play purchases using google reserved product ID: `android.test.purchased`.

When I try to purchase other products IDs I have in the developer console, they work fine, but when I try to purchase test product `android.test.purchases`, I get the following error message:

> Error retreiving information from server [DF-RPC-01]

What could be the problem?

Please note that I don't have any payment method put into my account yet.

Comment: I formatted the post and removed the thanking part (it's good to be polite, but here it only adds irrelevant text).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I should write what I came up with here.

regarding the response I am getting from Google when trying to buy a static reserved test id : "android.test.purchased". Unity has nothing to do with the response message "[DF-RPC-01]", it is coming from Google side. I tried to contact Google play console help about it, they escalated my case and promised to give feed back, but still there is no straightforward answer.

So I decided best thing to do is to add a credit card to my testing Gmail account (not the developer account - because I can't test purchases with it, again Google thing) and then I managed to pursue testing using my own products IDs I have on Google play console, and It worked just fine.

so my advice is to add your test email accounts to Google play console and test purchasing using your own products.

Wishing you all luck, Cheers, Rami Ibrahim